# Progressive tense, progressive aspect, continuing aspect or continuous tense?

Tags: terminology, progressive-aspect, continuous

I have heard four different names:

- **Progressive tense**
- **Progressive aspect**
- **Continuing aspect**
- **Continuous tense**

Which is the grammatically correct name approved by most grammar books and dictionaries? Or are they different terms and mean different things?

Comment: Because tense corresponds with "time". So I wouldn't consider "progressive" a tense. I call it a "progressive aspect". And we only have two tenses: present and past(the inflectional form of past tense is normally called preterite)

Comment: And even the tag used is "progressive-aspect".

Comment: Most of the time, *progressive aspect* and *continuous aspect* are used interchangeably and you can use them as such on ELL. Some grammar(ian)s observe the distinction, however, so we can't consider them synonymous for all intents and purposes in descriptions of all languages.

Answer (score 1):

Most importantly, let's not mess up [tense and aspect](http://www.elearnenglishlanguage.com/blog/learn-english/grammar/tense-aspect/).

> In grammar, the word **tense** refers to the time period in which the verb of a sentence places an action. For each grammatical tense, there are subcategories called aspects.
>
> **Aspect** refers to the duration of an event within a particular tense. In other words, the aspect of a tense allows us to describe or understand how an event unfolds over time. English has four aspects: simple, progressive , perfect , and perfect progressive.

Consequently, it would be incorrect to say things such as: **progressive tense, continuous tense, or continuing tense** as they are all **aspects**.

As regards the use of the three terms, progressive, continuous and continuing, all of them are correct, but **progressive**,  [statistically](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=continuous+aspect%2C+continuing+aspect%2C+progressive+aspect+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccontinuous%20aspect%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontinuing%20aspect%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprogressive%20aspect%3B%2Cc0) speaking, outscores the other two.